# How to make whole list item clickable

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could make the whole list item clickable and not just the words. In my list I am only able to click on the words.  How could I turn the whole list area into a link?  I have the list made with a link inside of it but I want you to be able to click anywhere inside the list area to get redirected.  Thank you.

And I am new to this website so I am sorry if I am asking this wrong.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/O5Ifvrw.gif

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the anchor tag a block element and let it control the height of the list item

here is a sample:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">click me!</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width:200px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    position: relative;
}
li a {
display:block;
    height:50px;
}
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/24ELw/

Answer (score 0):

You could just insert `buttons inside the list items` and style them borderless and without a background color -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lsAge/zL7R3/1/)